# how can i deepcopy list of objects in python

Tags: python, object, tkinter, copy

Hello guys i have been in this bug for 4 days and i still did not finish the project and never solved the bug.
the bug appears while im trying to deepcopy tkinter button in tictactoe project to check for player win in player vs pc mode, but everytime i copy a button and change it to x for example to check for win of the pc's enemy as if it is ai, it is also changing the original button that is breaking the app and couldn't do anything next.
this is the last step of my project. However, i tried numpy.copy() which didn't work and copy.deepcopy() which raised:

> TypeError: can't pickle _tkinter.tkapp objects

That's the part of the code that has the error specifically with the commented lines

```
def free_spot(i, j): # Check for free spots in the board
    return buttons_grid[i][j]['text'] == ''

def enemy_strategy():
        global turn

        corners = [[0, 0], [2, 0], [2, 2], [0, 2]]
        if len(free_places()) == 9:
            any_corner = rd.choice(corners)
            buttons_grid[any_corner[0]][any_corner[-1]].config(text='O')
            turn = 'player'
            sign_label.config(text='Your turn')

        elif free_spot(1, 1):
            buttons_grid[1][1].config(text='O')
            turn = 'player'

        else:
                 
            for x, i in enumerate(free_places()):
                grid_copy = array(buttons_grid)
                grid_copy[i[0]][i[-1]].config(text='O')

                # board_copy[i[0]][i[-1]] = np.copy(buttons_grid)
                # board_copy[..][..].config(text='X')

                if game_check(grid_copy) == 1:
                    buttons_grid[i[0]][i[-1]].config(text='O')
                    sign_label.config(text="Enemy Won!")
                    break
                
                # elif game_check(board_copy) == 1:
                #     return buttons_grid[..][..].config(text='O')
                # else:
                #     board_copy[..][..].config(text='')

                elif game_check(grid_copy) == 0:
                    buttons_grid[i[0]][i[-1]].config(text='O')
                    sign_label.config(text="Draw")
                    break

                elif game_check(grid_copy) == -1:
                    grid_copy[i[0]][i[-1]].config(text='')

                    if x == len(free_places())-1:
                        buttons_grid[i[0]][i[-1]].config(text='O')
                        turn = 'player'
                        sign_config(sign_label, 'Your')
                    else:
                        continue
```

I've already Done a Rock Paper Scissors app with tkinter and i'm always wanting to move forward and do a more complex project each time. please help me as if i'm still a beginner 18 years old

furthermore, i saw an algo called minimax but i think that over complexity compared to my level that's why i used normal functions and if statements instead of minimax

Thanks a lot in advance.

**Note: buttons_grid is a 3x3 nested list of tkinter buttons**

Comment: You can't generally deepcopy class objects unless the class provides methods for this. You should make a list of the data and copy that.

Comment: pls explain more, I do not use classes in my project but only functions, how can i get out of this bug

Comment: The `Tk` objects are class objects, they can't be copied.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot deep copy or pickle tkinter objects. There are no workarounds for that. Tkinter objects are just a wrapper around objects that exist inside of an embedded Tcl interpreter. This Tcl interpreter knows nothing about python objects and python has no way to pickle tcl objects.

Comment: suggest me a second way to do the job pls